# Killing equation in coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, vector-fields

In proving that it is possible to write the killing equation in coordinates as $$L_X g=0\iff X_{\alpha;\beta}+X_{\beta;\alpha}=0$$
I have read that the key observation, to write the equation in coordinates as above, is that when we consider the Levi-Civita connection we can replace the partial derivative with the covariant ones, i.e $Xg_{\sigma\beta}=\nabla_X g_{\sigma\beta}$.

This is my work, with $X=X^\alpha\partial_\alpha$:
$$L_X g=Xg_{\sigma \beta}-g([X,\partial_\sigma]\partial_\beta)-g(\partial_\sigma, [X,\partial_\beta])$$
But I can't understand why...can you help me?

Comment: Why don't you compute the Lie derivative and then plug in $\frac\partial{\partial^\alpha}$ and $\frac\partial{\partial^\beta}$ i.e $L_Xg(\frac\partial{\partial^\alpha}, \frac\partial{\partial^\beta})=0$.

Comment: @MBN This is exactly what I have done...see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that, for the Levi-Civita connection, we can find Riemann normal coordinates around any point P. In those coordinates $\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}=0$ and the ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=0$ at P. Now the formula for the Lie derivative
$$
[{\mathcal L}_Xg]_{\mu\nu}= X^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu} + g_{\mu\alpha}\partial_\nu X^\alpha + g_{\alpha\nu }\partial_\mu X^\alpha
$$
and the covariant derivative expression
$$
\nabla_{\mu}X_\nu + \nabla_\nu X_\mu
$$
coincide if   both $\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}=0$ and ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=0$. But both of these quanties are doubly-covariant tensors and    if two tensors of the same type coincide in one system of coordinates, they coincide in all coordinate systems.

We conclude that
$$
[{\mathcal L}_Xg]_{\mu\nu} =\nabla_{\mu}X_\nu + \nabla_\nu X_\mu
$$
at the point P  --- but P is an arbitrary point,  so the two expressions coincide everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! So the fact that I can consider to take the normal coordinates around an arbitrary point $p$, tells me that since the christoffel's symbols are zero,  then the covariant derivative can be replaced by the partial one and viceversa?

Comment: Exactly!   It is important to remember that being able to set the ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=0$ at an arbitrary point is a property only of the Levi-Cita connection. It does not hold for connections with torsion. This, and he fact that we have local intertial frames (on a scale such that we can ignore tidal forces) in which  ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=0$   is why GR uses the torsion-free LC connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot now it is all clear!